# Ignore Junit test from the parent abstract class

Tags: junit, annotations, abstract-class, junit4

I have a big set of unit test that needs to be ignored for a while and alle these unit tests are extending an Abstract class like this:

```
public class MyAbstractTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public void init(){

        //global init for all unit tests
    }

    public void some_parent_methods(){
        // some code
    }
}
```

I was thinking just adding the `@Ignore` on the Abstract will ignore all the sub-tests but it does not to work like this.

Is there any way to do it (with Junit 4.x) instead putting `@Ignore` on all the subclasses (especially if there are hundreds of them) ?

Comment: Isn't this more a question for the build tool you're using?

Comment: @imrichardcole perhaps, but I got the same behaviour (not ignoring if annotation on the abstract) with maven and from the Eclipse environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a good way (and quick) to temporarily disable the whole set of test using an abstract:

I just added the following code in the abstract class:

```
@Before
public void init() {
    Assume.assumeTrue(false);
}
```

It does not use the `@Ignore` annotation, but at the end all test are skipped the same way like if it was using it.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Categories` will do what you want:

http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.html

Comment: With this, it needs to refactor all the existing test to "categorize" the tests. But it looks very interesting to use them.